# Jquery, remove href from parent li only

Tags: jquery, href

In a wordpress theme, I am using the wp_list_pages() function to generate the list of pages and its working great however I need help making one of the links redundant.

This is what wp_list_pages is outputting and the one that I need to change:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://mysite.com/page3">Page 3</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page4">Page 4</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

I would like this to be

```
<li class="page_item page-item-12">Page 3 
<ul>
 <li><a >Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

This is the JQuery that I am using:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(".page-item-12 a").removeAttr("href");
 });
 </script>
```

However, the Jquery is removing the links from all the  < li > in the child ul as well which I do not want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('ul').find('li:has(ul)').children('a').removeAttr('href')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wa2dR/)

Comment: That removes the the whole link and doesn't leave the text, which is needed so the user can hover over and see the secondary  < UL>

Comment: @MarkPetherbridge do you want to keep the `a` element without `href` or it can be removed? For `Page 3` you have removed `a` but for `Page 4` you have kept `a` but removed `href` which is correct

Comment: Andy, Right sorry to mess you around, Can we make that go up one level? so that page 4 is also linked? The 'a' can be either removed or not. No fuss on that point

Comment: @MarkPetherbridge so you just want the `href` attribute to be removed?

Comment: yeah. what is the update URL - it isnt working on mine - still the old one

Comment: on that link, page 4 is still not linked :S

Comment: @MarkPetherbridge can you update the desired o/p to correct format

Answer (score 0):

Use the child selector for this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(".page-item-12>a").removeAttr("href");
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.page-item-12').children('ul').find('a').first().prop('href', '');
```